# Python Bug? What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I'm trying to make a simple iterator which cycles through a list and returns three consecutive numbers  from the list in python, but I get really weird result - code works fine only when numbers in the list are in ascending order.

```
import itertools
c=[0,1,2,3,0,5,6]
counter=itertools.cycle(c)
def func(x):
    if x==len(c)-1:
        return c[x],c[0],c[1]
    elif x==len(c)-2:
        return c[x],c[len(c)-1],c[0]
    else:
        return c[x],c[x+1],c[x+2]

for i in range(len(c)+2):
    print(func(next(counter)))
```

'Im trying to make a simple iterator which cycles through a list and returns three consecutive numbers  from the list in python, but I get really weird result - code works fine only when numbers in the list are in ascending order.Atom prints the following in the 5th tuple. Please help..

```
(0, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 0)
(3, 0, 5)
(0, 1, 2)
(5, 6, 0)
(6, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
```

'

Comment: It would be useful if you specified what the *expected* output should look like. It is unclear from the code what you actually want to do.

Comment: For the fifth value `x` is `0`. For that case you return return `c[x],c[x+1],c[x+2]`. That is `(0, 1, 2)`. What would you expect and why?

Comment: Thanks for reply, basicaly I would like to make code that cycle an array in three consecutive values of array with step 1. Say c=[1,2,3,4]  result : (1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,1,2),(1,2,3) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing the values of c and the indices. It seems in `func` you expect that an index is passed but you are in fact passing a value from `c`. NOTE: `counter` is cycling over the *values* of c not over indices.

Also please note that in python you can use negative indices so you can write `c[-1]` as a short of `c[len(c) - 1]`.

Comment: it returns mistake only in the middle of the result though...

Comment: yes because values match the indices for everything but the second zero

Comment: need to digest that, thnx Ivaylo)